# SQL Query optimization -performance issues

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I have the following SQL query I want to optimize :

```
select table1.tiers as col1, table1.id_item as col2 
from items table1 
where (table1.tiers is not null) 
  and table1.tiers<>''
  and table1.id_item = (select max(table2.id_item)
                        from items table2
                        where table1.tiers=table2.tiers) 
  and table1.n_version_item=(select max(table2.n_version_item) 
                             from items table2 
                             where table2.id_item=table1.id_item)
```

I tried this:

```
select table1.tiers as col1, table1.id_item as col2 
from items table1 
where (table1.tiers is not null) 
  and table1.tiers<> '' 
  and CONCAT(table1.id_item,table1.n_version_item) =  (select CONCAT(max(table2.id_item),max(table2.n_version_item)) 
                                                       from items table2
                                                       where table2.id_item=table1.id_item 
                                                         and table1.tiers=table2.tiers)
```

But I'am not getting the same result. Original first query is returning fewer rows than the modified one. Note that table items has a primary key (id,version) and for each couple a tier can be affected.

Comment: Don't re-use the same table alias (table1) in a query.

Comment: `where (id_item, n_version_item) = (select max(t2.id_item), max(t2.n_version_item) from ...)`

Comment: I know that SQL is just a query language. The first query was generated by hibernate. And I noticed in log files that it takes too long. This is why I want to rewrite it in another way in order to solve the performance issue
thankx

Comment: I 'am using MySQL

Comment: @user3474488 how much items table contains data ?

Comment: @Moudiz exactly 3404 rows

Comment: @user3474488 its a few data it shouldn't cause performance issue. you can create an index because in your query you are not using PK

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

When using a function , it will prevent the index to be used , so `CONCAT(table1.id_item,table1.n_version_item)` will not read an index unless if its Function based index. however as `a_horse_with_no_name` mentioned in comments you can use the below :

```
select itm.tiers as col1, itm.id_item as col2 
from items itm
where itm.tiers is not null 
  and itm.tiers<>''
  and (itm.id_item , itm.n_version_item)= (select 
 max(item_sub.id_item),max(item_sub.n_version_item)
                        from items item_sub
                        where itm.tiers=item_sub.tiers)
```

Then you have to check the query plan of the query what index is using ( you can start an index with column `tiers` and other index on `id_item` and `n_version_item` )

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select i.tiers as col1, i.id_item as col2 
from items i 
where i.tiers is not null and  -- redundant, but I'm leaving it in
      i.tiers <> '' 
      (id_item, n_version_item) = (select i2.id_item, max(i2.n_version_item)
                                   from items i2
                                   where i2.tiers = i.tiers
                                   order by i2.id_item desc, i2.n_version_item desc
                                   limit 1
                                  );
```

For this version, you want an index on `items(tiers, id_item, n_version_item)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you hide a column inside a 'function' (`CONCAT`, `DATE`, etc, etc), no index can be used to help performance.  This eliminates your second version from consideration.

Related to that is the use of "Row Constructors" (see a_horse_with_no_name's Comment).  They have historically been poorly optimized; avoid them.  I am referring to `WHERE (a,b) IN ( (1,2), ...)` or other variants.

Now, let's dissect

```
  and table1.id_item = (select max(table2.id_item)
                    from items table2
                    where table1.tiers=table2.tiers)
```

`table2` needs `INDEX(tiers, id_item)` in that order.  With such, the subquery is very fast.  The other subquery needs `INDEX(id_item, n_version_item)`  Those feed into the rest:

```
  and table1.id_item = <<value>>
```

Now let's look at the whole

```
where (table1.tiers is not null) 
  and  table1.tiers<>''
  and  table1.id_item = <<value>>
  and  table1.n_version_item = <<value>>
```

`=` is easy to optimize; the others are not.  So let's build

```
INDEX(id_item, n_version_item,  -- in either order
      tiers)    -- last
```

By using the order I specified, you can avoid also needing `INDEX(id_item, n_version_item)` that was mentioned above.

(It would help if you provided `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; I need to know what the PK is, and some other things.)

As a bonus, these indexes will be "covering indexes".

As a final note (a minor one):

```
where (table1.tiers is not null) 
  and  table1.tiers<>''
```

It would be better to decide on only *one* encoding (`NULL` vs empty string) to whatever you are indicating by such.